# Docker container automatically stopping after running command docker run

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to dockerize MySQL and Spring Boot application however whenever I try to run my docker container and connect my docker image to the network the container automatically stops running.I'm new to docker so any help well is appreciated.

```
C:\Users\shawn>docker run --name mysqldb --network springboot -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=passion -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7
54d2a7c0ec819ec5e8e550ad61f55e8aabc7783ffad12d1ae04e79e7925d8064

C:\Users\shawn>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

I've tried using docker starting and using docker run with a specific port but still getting the same error.

Comment: Check `docker ps -a` and `docker logs` to figure out why it exited.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the error running the docker logs command.